# How to do a join from one source table to 3 different fields?

Tags: oracle

I have a Table with main records IDs and Sub IDs.
I have an Oracle-table "Records", like this:

```
'Records' TABLE STRUCTURE:

| main_id  | sub_id1 | sub_id2 | sub_id3 | 
------------------------------------------
| 1        | 100     | 202     | 350     |
| 2        | 101     | 203     | 375     |
| 3        | 102     | 204     | 400     |
| 4        | 103     | 205     | 2000    |
```

Now I would like to get the names of the sub_ids from a different table that have the names of all the sub_ids in one column.
I have an Oracle-table "Name", like this:

```
'Name' TABLE STRUCTURE:

| sub_id    | id_name | 
-----------------------
| 100       | Gamma   |
| 202       | Phi     |
| 350       | Betta   |
```

I basically need to join the different sub_ids and display each name in one table.

```
'Result' TABLE STRUCTURE:

| main_id  | sub_id1 | id_name1| sub_id2 | id_name2| sub_id3 | id_name3 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1        | 100     | Gamma   | 202     | Phi     | 350     | Betta    |      
| 2        | ...     | ...     | ...     |
```

I've tried multiple versions of the following query with different joins and cannot get anywhere. Thank you for your help!

```
SELECT 
records.main-id,
records.sub_id1, 
name.id_name as id_name1, 
records.sub_id2, 
name.id_name as id_name2,
records.sub_id3, 
name.id_name as id_name3,
FROM  records, Name
WHERE 
records.sub_id1 = name.id_name
OR records.sub_id2 = name.id_name
OR records.sub_id3 = name.id_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this using a series of 3 inner joins, all to the same `Name` table:

```
SELECT r.main_id, r.sub_id1, n1.id_name AS id_name1,
                  r.sub_id2, n2.id_name AS id_name2,
                  r.sub_id3, n3.id_name AS id_name3
FROM records r
INNER JOIN name n1
    ON r.sub_id1 = n1.sub_id
INNER JOIN name n2
    ON r.sub_id2 = n2.sub_id
INNER JOIN name n3
    ON r.sub_id3 = n3.sub_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just join on the `name` table thrice, once per column you want to get:

```
SELECT r.main-id,
       r.sub_id1, 
       n1.id_name as id_name1, 
       r.sub_id2, 
       n2.id_name as id_name2,
       r.sub_id3, 
       n3.id_name as id_name3,
FROM   records r
JOIN   name n1 ON r.sub_id1 = n1.sub_id
JOIN   name n2 ON r.sub_id2 = n2.sub_id
JOIN   name n3 ON r.sub_id3 = n3.sub_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.main_id , t1.sub_id1  , t2.id_name , t2.sub_id, t1.sub_id2 , t1.sub_id3, t3.id_name,t4.id_name
FROM records t1 INNER JOIN NAME t2 ON t1.sub_id1=t2.sub_id INNER JOIN NAME t3
ON t1.sub_id3=t3.sub_id INNER JOIN NAME t4 ON t1.sub_id2=t4.sub_id;
```